# Andengine GLES2 - Proper way to load one BitmapTextureAtlas for several TextureRegion

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm new in Andengine and somewhere I found that If you want use one BitmapTextureAtlas for several ButtonSprites/Sprites you have to do it like this

```
BitmapTextureAtlas texAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 316, 1062, TextureOptions.NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TextureRegion pistolActive = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, activity.getApplicationContext(), POWERUP_TEXTURE_PATH, 0, 0);
        pistolActive.set(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);

        TextureRegion pistolUnactive = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, activity.getApplicationContext(), POWERUP_TEXTURE_PATH, 0, 0);
        pistolUnactive.set(0, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);

        TextureRegion pistolDeactive = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, activity.getApplicationContext(), POWERUP_TEXTURE_PATH, 0, 0);
        pistolDeactive.set(0, TILE_HEIGHT * 2, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        texAtlas.load();

        ButtonSprite button = new ButtonSprite(0, 0, pistolActive, pistolUnactive, pistolDeactive, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new ButtonSprite.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final ButtonSprite buttonSprite, float v, float v2) {
            }
        });
    }
```

But now I check and if you put `texAtlas.load()` before loop-for it will work too. But what's the best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapTextureAtlas texAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 316, 1062, TextureOptions.NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        TextureRegion pistolActive = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, activity.getApplicationContext(), POWERUP_TEXTURE_PATH, 0, 0);
        pistolActive.set(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);

        TextureRegion pistolUnactive = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, activity.getApplicationContext(), POWERUP_TEXTURE_PATH, 0, 0);
        pistolUnactive.set(0, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);

        TextureRegion pistolDeactive = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, activity.getApplicationContext(), POWERUP_TEXTURE_PATH, 0, 0);
        pistolDeactive.set(0, TILE_HEIGHT * 2, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        texAtlas.load();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ButtonSprite button = new ButtonSprite(0, 0, pistolActive, pistolUnactive, pistolDeactive, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new ButtonSprite.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final ButtonSprite buttonSprite, float v, float v2) {
                }
            });
        }
```

No need to create texture regions multiple times.So do this manner.

Actually If you load in this way, you will get some UI problems.
So my suggestion is use different textures for different sprites to load

If you want to avoid loading problems then you can go for Sprite sheets(eg.. TexturePacker)